# Download multiple powershell files from Azure Storage container as a Zip

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, zip, azure-web-app-service

How to download all the PowerShell files from the Azure storage
account container to a zip folder through power shell cmdlets?

As of now, the below cmdlet helps to download a specific blob by its name

```
$blob = Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container hemac -Blob "CreateAndDeploy-Eventhubs.ps1" -Context $ctx -Destination $f -Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set a folder to download all the blobs

1.Provide the full path to a directory you wish to use for downloaded blob

```
$DestinationFolder = "<C:\DownloadedBlobs>"
```

Create the destination directory and download the blob

```
New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory -Force
$blob | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent –Destination $DestinationFolder
```

Now zip the entire folder.

```
$folderToZip = "C:\DownloadedBlobs"
$rootfolder = Split-Path -Path $folderToZip
$zipFile = Join-Path -Path $rootfolder -ChildPath "ZippedFile.zip"
```

Then you should use this - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6)

```
Compress-Archive -Path $folderToZip -DestinationPath $zipFile -Verbose
```

The zipped file will be in the same directory as the download folder